# How to encode special characters in path parameter while testing Restful service through swagger

Tags: swagger-ui

How can I encode special characters (@444&%*%&%*&%*%*&) in path parameter in swagger UI

When I browse the below URL, getting A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)
http://localhost/MyApp/services/v1/Customer/%40444%26%25*%25%26%25*%26%25*%25*%26/Orders